# bash configuration templating

Tags: bash, templates, scripting, templating

I am using a bash script to install and configuration an application. I am trying to use a template where I can fill in values from variables and then save it to its proper location. This works fine with just variables, but I am unable to use any conditionals. Are there any better ways of doing this?

Heres my example template:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cat <<EOF
    DEFAULTS: &DEFAULTS
      adapter: $DB
      host: $DB_HOST
      username: $DB_USER
      password: $DB_PASS
      database: $DB_DATABASE
      if [ ! $DB_RECONNECT = ""]; then
        reconnect: $DB_RECONNECT
      fi
      if [ ! $DB_TIMEOUT = ""]; then
        timeout: $DB_TIMEOUT  
      fi
    EOF
```

And then I use `source template.sh > /path/to/file` to evaluate and save the file.

Comment: think about what's happening, would you expect a `cat`ed file to execute? That's what your doing right?, except that the source of the file to `cat` is provided by the `<<EOF` here-document. So why not follow your `source template > file` with `chmod 755 file; ./file` to execute the logic inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to enclose everything in the heredoc

```
cat <<EOF
...
database: $DB_DATABASE
EOF

if [ -z "$DB_RECONNECT" ]; then
    echo "reconnect: $DB_RECONNECT"
fi

if [ -z "$DB_TIMEOUT" ]; then
    echo "timeout: $DB_TIMEOUT"
fi
```

Comment: I didn't even think of doing it that way... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `tpage` like in this simple example :

```
$ cat /tmp/l.tpl 
DEFAULTS: [%def%]
    adapter[%db%]

$ tpage --define def=foo --define db=bar --interpolate /tmp/l.tpl
DEFAULTS: foo
    adapterbar
```

`tpage` is a command coming with the well known `Perl` module `Template::Toolkit`, but no need to know `Perl` to use it. You can do some conditional as well, see [conditional](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/perl/0596004761/template-directives/perltt-chp-4-sect-5)

Project : http://www.template-toolkit.org/